# Firebird 2.5 insert row to existing table

Tags: sql, database, insert, firebird2.5

I have table TABLE1 in a Firebird 2.5 database and want to insert multiple rows.

script:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, IDPREDEK, ICO, DIC, FIRMA, MISTO, ULICE, PSC, CISSML, CISEVID, PLATOD, PLATDO, JMENO, PRIJMENI, TITUL, FUNKCE, TELEFON, TELEFON2, FAX, EMAIL, ODP_JMENO, ODP_PRIJMENI, ODP_TITUL, ODP_FUNKCE, ODP_TELEFON, ODP_TELEFON2, ODP_FAX, ODP_EMAIL, D_INIDOP, D_INISETR, D_KATPRAC, POCETMUZI, POCETZENY, HASCHILD, HASCHILD1, HASCHILD2, POZNAMKA) 
VALUES (91, 89, NULL, NULL, 'CLY0010702 - PHM-LPH_DEPO / PRG/RSM/FSB/PHM', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'N', 'N', 'N', NULL);
```

And problem is this error :

```
Error while importing to table TABLE1:
Engine Error (code = 335544665)
violation of PRIMARY or UNIGUE KEY constraint
"PK_TABLE1" on table "FIRMY".
Problematic key value is ("ID=95).
SQL Error (code= -803):
Invalid insert or update value(s): object columns are constrained - no 2 table rows can have duplicate column values.
```

In TABLE1 is last ID number 94, I don't have two same rows with ID 95.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Your trigger definition is incomplete, it doesn't specify the table it is applied to (presumably `TABLE1`), please update your question to correct this. Also, please ask only one question in a question. You now have two questions, and you don't provide enough information to answer the first. So, edit to remove one of those two questions and post the other question as a new question.

Comment: there is only one question, how to insert row to TABLE1, IF add ID manualy i got first error, when i leave ID as NULL, resive second error. and i place what is in TRG_TABLE1_AIO

Comment: No, you have two questions: one about the constraint violation, and another about the trigger. They are not the same problem, not related, and the solution to both will be different. And if you think they are the same problem (but really, they are not), then at minimum you should provide **all** relevant DDL of that table, including indexes, constraints and triggers.

Comment: The code shown inserts id 91 into table1, while the error message talks about ID 95 in table FIRMY. Please make sure to show all relevant DDL, triggers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is your `ID` identity. If so just leave it out of `insert into()` and `values()`.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution, replace ID :

```
... VALUES (GEN_ID(GEN_TABLE1 , 1), 91, NULL, NULL, ...
```